# Docker: Cannot start mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, ubuntu

I have a Docker container with mysql. Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
USER root
RUN apt-get update
#RUN apt-get -y install default-jre
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y libmysqlclient-dev
RUN apt-get install -y python-mysqldb
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y git
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

# install packages
RUN \
  apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  ssh \
  rsync \
  vim \
  openjdk-8-jdk

# create ssh keys
RUN \
  ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa && \
  cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && \
  chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

#RUN apt-get install -y mysql-server
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y mysql-client
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y mysql-server
RUN mkdir /run/mysqld
RUN chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql /run/mysqld && \
     service mysql start
```

I am able to build the images without any issues, but when i exec into the container and try to run mysql, i get errors

```
docker exec -it myContainer bash
root@fe34sgjd989fh:/root#mysql -uroot -ppassword
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

then i tried

```
root@fe34sgjd989fh:/root#service mysql start
* Starting MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                                                                              [fail]
```

when i look at `/var/log/mysql/error.log` i see

```
2019-04-03T22:09:12.829745Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2019-04-03T22:09:12.838374Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table storage engine for 'db' doesn't have this option
2019-04-03T22:09:12.838469Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Failed to initialize ACL/grant/time zones structures or failed to remove temporary table files.
2019-04-03T22:09:12.838597Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

what does it mean? Here is my mysql.cnf file

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size     = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_open_cache       = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log     = 1
#slow_query_log_file    = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
```

what am i doing wrong? I want to star the docker container with mysql running

Comment: I suggest looking at the official builds: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql. You don't have a service manager during the build process. The official builds have enough hooks for adding /configuring things so why are you building your own? If python/jdk are needed aren't these for an application that should be in a different container and then co-start them with docker-compose?

Comment: so should i just copy the contents of the Dockerfile at https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/8.0/Dockerfile
?

Comment: I think you should just use the prebuild dockerhub image built from these but its hard to see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: So i want my docker container to have mysql. What should i specify in the Dockerfile if i want to have mysql installed in my container?

Comment: What else do you want running in the container? Because containers are typically 1 process or process group. Expand on what you are doing, because the current approach isn't clear and without it there isn't a single answer.

Comment: ok, so ultimately, i want to run hive and hadoop inside the container. i have some hive queries that i want to run in the container

Comment: Use multiple containers. Create a docker compose definition so they are all interconnected as a group.

Answer (score 1):

A docker file cannot run `service mysql start` at the build stage as the docker image for ubuntu doesn't have a system manager which `service` talks to.

Based on the extended discussion it is recommended you use the upstream mysql container and extend your functionality in different containers, and the collect them using docker-compose to start together.